# Writing a list of lists to a seperate text file, one file per a list with in that list

Tags: python

so I am trying to write a list of lists to seperate files.
Each list contains 100 string objects or less. The goal is keep a text file less than 100 lines no more than that.

To do that, i split a list but now i am having an issue writing them to a file.
So essentialy write a list within a list to its own separate file. There are total of 275 strings objects in total

```
size=100
list_ofList_flows=[parameter_list[i:i+size] for i  in range(0,len(parameter_list), size)]
 #above list_ofList_flows contains [100][100][75] in terms of length

fileNumbers = int(math.ceil((len(parameter_list) / 100)))
#fileNumbers is 3, because we have 3 sets of lists[100, 100, 75]

i = 0
while i < fileNumbers:

    for flowGroup in list_ofList_flows:
        f = open("workFlow_sheet" + str(i) + ".txt", "w")

        for flo in flowGroup:
            f.write(flo + '\n')



    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Please improve your code formatting and provide sample in- and output.

Comment: You don't `close()` each file within the `for` loop and you increment `i` outside of the `while` loop. You also don't actually ask a question so we don't know what's going wrong (assuming your indentation is correct in your code)

Comment: @roganjosh sorry, formatted it better. They are already being written to files. Hwoever, all 3 files have the same data... some logic i am missing here with for loop. It's only writting first 100 string objects not the remaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work. I had to use `random` to generate some data, into a list that was 275 elements long.

```
import random

def chunks(l, n):
    n = max(1, n)
    return [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

data = [random.randint(0, 10) for x in range(275)]

chunked_data = chunks(data, 100)

for file_num, sublist in enumerate(chunked_data):
    with open("workFlow_sheet{}.txt".format(file_num), 'w') as outfile:
        for item in sublist:
            outfile.write(str(item) + '\n')
```

Essentially, sub-divide your data into nested lists of maximum length of 100, and then write the contents of each nested list to a unique file.

**EDIT**

I couldn't actually reproduce your problem in terms of each file containing the same data. However, you incremented `i` in the wrong scope (it needs an extra level of indentation, I think you overwrote each file multiple times in your code) and you did not `close()` the files on each iteration. The use of `with` (the Python [context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)) just means that it automatically closes the file once the operations are complete. I *think* this is a working tweak of your original code... albeit with a random list generated.

```
import random
import math

parameter_list = [random.randint(0, 10) for x in range(275)]

size=100
list_ofList_flows=[parameter_list[i:i+size] for i  in range(0,len(parameter_list), size)]
 #above list_ofList_flows contains [100][100][75] in terms of length

fileNumbers = int(math.ceil((len(parameter_list) / 100)))
#fileNumbers is 3, because we have 3 sets of lists[100, 100, 75]

i = 0
while i < fileNumbers:

    for flowGroup in list_ofList_flows:
        f = open("workFlow_sheet" + str(i) + ".txt", "w")

        for flo in flowGroup:
            f.write(str(flo) + '\n')
        f.close()


        i = i + 1
```

Comment: Perfecto! With open is the key here right. Could you tell me where i was going wrong?

Comment: @dedpo just about to start looking into that, and also going to try make my answer a little cleaner

Comment: @dedpo edited, and also cleaned my code up to use `enumerate` to get rid of the `iterator_count`. Hopefully that clarifies.